# pilgrim hat butt-pipe

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Aaah! You stained my **pilgrim hat butt-pipe**!*

Source: https://southpark.fandom.com/wiki/Starvin%27_Marvin/Script

Can you please clarify to me the expression "pilgrim hat butt-pipe"? The official translator of South Park to my native language translates it simply as “missionary hat”. But what is "butt-pipe" in the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nothing special.  He is using "butt pipe" as an insult.  He is calling the other person a "butt pipe" to insult him.

The characters who say this are parodies of mindless children's television.  Their basic joke is that they fart at each other. Here they are doing a "thanksgiving themed program" which means that they fart at each other while wearing pilgrim clothes.  One farts at the other's head, getting poo on his hat.  The other is upset so complains "You stained my pilgrim hat, butt pipe"

It's not very deep.